# The Steiner tree problem for the hypercube graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Fix an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $G = (V,E)$ be the graph with a node for each binary vector of length $n$ and an edge (of weight $1$) connecting two nodes if their bitstrings differ by a single bit. This is equivalent to having a node for each vertex of an $n$ dimensional (hyper)cube and an edge of the graph for each edge of the cube.

Now given a subset $S\subseteq V$ is there a "good" way to find a minimum tree which is a subgraph of $G$ and contains all of the vertices in $S$?

Of course there is an equivalent formulation where the initial graph is the complete graph on $2^n$ vertices and two nodes are connected by an edge of weight given by the Hamming-weight of their sum (mod $2$).

Followup/alternative question, I expect the answer to the above is either "no" or completely unknown, although I do not know. I would therefore also be interested in any methods which find a "reasonably small" spanning tree rather than a strictly minimal one.

Note that for a general graph the Steiner tree problem is hard, and a wide variety of algorithms have been published to (approximately) solve it however the case I stated above is highly specific and potentially (hopefully) the large amount of structure in the graph allows some simplifications.

It may be relevant that this is for a real, relatively practical, application (I have some computer code that can be sped up by finding good trees connecting randomly sampled points in this graph). Example numbers relevant to this application are $n$ of the order of $60-100$ and $\left|S\right|$ in the range of $10^7-10^9$. As you can see from these numbers the ratio $\frac{|S|}{|V|}$ is very small which may impact the relevant algorithms.

Comment: This sounds like [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree), and of course, efficient algorithms are known.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @saulspatz the minimum spanning tree is for the whole graph (i.e. the tree contains all of the vertices of the graph), I want the minimum tree which spans a (strict) subset of the vertices. This is the Steiner tree problem and in general is quite hard.

Comment: Yes, I missed the "subset" part.  Sorry.